# Adding additional attribute in <html> tag from nested page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, master-pages

I have a tag `<html>` in `master page`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

from another page that uses this master page I want to add one more attribute, finally I want to generate something like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
          prefix="ya: http://webmaster.yandex.ru/vocabularies/">
```

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your master set the tag to runat=server and give it an id like this:

```
<html lang="en" runat="server" id="masterHead">
```

In your masterpage .cs add this to set the property:

```
 public string SetPrefix
 {
    set { masterHead.Attributes.Add("prefix", value); }
 }
```

Then from your content page you can set it like this:

```
var master = Master as SiteMaster;

if (master != null)
((SiteMaster)Master).SetPrefix = "ya: http://webmaster.yandex.ru/vocabularies/";
```

In the above SiteMaster is your MasterPage, you may have to change it to the actual name of your MasterPage.

[image: Demo image]

Comment: SiteMaster is the MasterPage, it is just the default one that is used in a new web application. You will have to rename that to your masterpage name.